# Avoid repetition of Dependency Scope for all dependencies that have the same scope

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, dependency-management

I've a maven project where all the dependencies have `<scope>test</scope>`. Is there a way to avoid this repetition on every dependency (I know compile time scope is one where this is possible)

Answer (score 0):

In short - It is not possible as far as I know.

Why?

You don't have to explicitly set compile scope only because it is **default** value for the scope.

From [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope)

> compile
>
> This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile
>   dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>   Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

Currently, maven does not support chaning of dependency efault scope. It is not a standard use case.

You could maybe create property set to your scope

```
<properties>
    <dependency-scope>test</dependency-scoppe>
</properties>
```

But that would require to reference it in dependency definition and i think that is not something what you want (That may be used in cases where you need to switch some deps between compile and provided based on active profile)

```
<scope>${dependency-scope}</scope>
```